# Why not shift the index of the derivative in Euler series?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I'm reading over solving linear differential equations with analytic coefficients, and finding the solutions that are near regular singular points.  In the earlier section on solving similar equations near ordinary points, when you assume the Taylor series of a solution and compute a derivative, sensibly, the index of the sum shifts.  For instance, if $\displaystyle y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{x}$ then $\displaystyle y' = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n-1}$.

However, when in the context of finding a solution near a regular singular point, we assume $\displaystyle y = x^{r}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{x}x^{n}$ and after pushing the $x^{r}$ inside the sum, in the book I'm reading, the derivative is given by $\displaystyle y' = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+r)a_{n}x^{n+r-1}$.  Why is it that the index doesn't also shift here?

My guess about the answer to this question is:  Well, if $r$ is large, then by taking a derivative you don't necessarily lose a constant term, so the index should remain where it was.

But then my question to *that* is:  Ok, so long as $r>0$ then that's true for the first derivative.  But the book also doesn't shift index for the second derivative, and *there* if $r=1$ then by taking two derivatives you will lose a constant term.  Shouldn't this be a consideration in solving these equations?

In fact, an example given in my book had $r=1$ as one of the solutions for $r$ and yet the index wasn't shifted.  Is this legitimate?

Answer (score 1):

When the exponent on $x$ is zero, the derivative with respect to $x$ is zero.  Therefore the sum

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$

has derivative

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}$$

as the $a_0x^0$ term becomes $0$ after deriving.

In contrast, for $r\gt 0$ our sum

$$x^r\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^{n+r}$$
derives as
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+r)a_nx^{n+r-1}\tag 1$$

As you correctly guessed, if $r=0$ then this reduces to the previous form, where the $n=0$ term vanishes.

For the second derivative, assuming that $r\ge1$ then we have a $0$ in the first term.  This is ok, and really it would be ok to leave the indexing unshifted in the first derivative too since only a zero term is removed.  It would be similar to including $0!$ in a multiplicative definition of the factorial function; we need only multiply down to $1$ (or $2$ really), but we define $0!=1$ and so nothing is gained or lost by including the extra term or removing it.

Comment: Right, that was my guess about the answer. What about the second part? What if $r=1$ and you take two derivatives, as my textbook did?

Comment: The zero coefficient takes care of the index shifting in both cases, I would guess that the authors may have some historical basis for shifting the index in one case but not the other

Comment: If I understand what you mean, you are suggesting that a_0 = 0. If so then suppose in solving the indicial you get r=5. In that case, the first term of a solution would be a sixth power. But then that would imply that you also should have been able to find a solution without a_0 not equal to 0 and r=6. Is this right?

Comment: No, I am saying that the derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$, and when $n=0$ then the coefficient of this term becomes $0$.  Even if $a_0\neq 0$ when we have $n\cdot a_nx^{n-1}$ we get $0$ when $n=0$.